# Error de integración Oracle BI Publisher y Oracle Forms12c

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Estoy haciendo algunas pruebas con Oracle Forms 12c y con Oracle BI Publisher 11g Trial Edition (v11.1.1.7.1), todos los forms compilan bien, pero cuando los ejecuto aparece un error:"FRM-41223: BI Publisher integration error"

Este es mi código, es un program unit que se activa cuando presiono un botón

```
PROCEDURE EJECUTA_BIP IS
bi_username varchar2(20);
bi_password varchar2(20);
repid REPORT_OBJECT;
v_rep varchar2(256);
rep_status varchar2(256);
v_xmlpserver varchar2(256);
BEGIN
-- Servidor de BI Publisher
v_xmlpserver := 'http://HOST:PORT/xmlpserver/';
bi_username := 'username';
bi_password := 'password';

-- Identify the Report Object.
repid := find_report_object ('BIP_P');--nombre del reporte

-- Before reaching this point be sure to obtain the username and password 
for BI-Pub.
-- Pass in the username and password. This is required.
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_USER, bi_username);
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_PASSWORD, bi_password);

--
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_SSL_CONNECTION, OPTIONAL);
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_SERVICE_LOCATION, 
v_xmlpserver||'/services/v2/ScheduleService?wsdl');
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_PATH, '/Samples/1. 
Overview/Salary Report.xdo');
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_LOCALE, 'ES-es');
--Tipo de formato de salida, p.e.: html,pdf,rtf,xslx,csv
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY (repid, BIP_REPORT_FORMAT, 'pdf');

-- Ask BIP to run the report.
v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(repid);
END;
```

El problema esta en la última linea, cuando ejecuta el **RUN_REPORT_OBJECT**, me parece que devuelve un objeto null.
Alguien sabe como puedo arreglar eso!
Estoy usando una versión Trial de BI Publisher , esto afectará en algo?
Ocupo su ayuda!
Saludos!